# datetime tostring format changes date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

I am merely trying to format a datetime object but it appears to be changing the date. In the first line below, the value of ProcessBeginDate is #11/1/2014. As you can see in the image below, after assigning to a string and applying formatting, the string value is "2014-00-01".

How have I managed this??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [custom date format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `mm` is the specifier for a 2-digit minute.  The correct specifier for a 2-digit month is `MM`, so your format string should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.